# wtforms how is data supplied from user request to form?

Tags: wtforms

here is basic flask get/post application:

```
@app.route('/foo', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def fooapp():
   form = SomeForm()


   if form.validate_on_submit():
     /* do something with posted data */
   else:
     /* render html for forms to receive user input */
```

It seems like `process(formdata)` method of wtforms' Form object reads from request. but I never called that method; all I did was checking whether the request method was POST and `form` had no errors while validating user input. How, and when did my form read from request data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using the Flask-WTF library, their [documentation goes into this convienence](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WTF/#api-changes) of not having to supply the `request.form`:

> You don’t need to pass request.form into your form instance, as the Form automatically populates from request.form unless alternate data is specified. Pass in None to suppress this. Other arguments are as with wtforms.Form.